# Can't find System.ComponentModel.Composition with .NET Framework 4 installed

Tags: mvvm, mef, caliburn

i think this sounds like a stupid question. i am starting with [caliburn micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/): [customizing the bootstraper](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customizing%20The%20Bootstrapper&referringTitle=Documentation). i have .NET Framework 4 installed, VS2010. but when i try to add a `using`, there is intellisense that tells me i have System.ComponentModel.Design but no Composition or any of

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives;
```

available. i tried to add a reference but cannot find System.ComponentModel in the list even

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have the Managed Extensibility Framework installed?  [MSDN says that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.aspx) `System.ComponentModel.Composition` is part of MEF.

Assuming that MEF is already included in .NET 4, you will also need to add a reference to *System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll* to your project.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are targeting a 3.5 framework. That's why you can't find the system.componentmodel.composition. And if you already change your target to 4.0 and still you can't see the composition. all you have to do is go to project then add reference then find the system.componentmmodel.composition. Once you already added it. You can already see the composition. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: You might need to update your .NET framework. 
Download it [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net462-developer-pack-offline-installer). 
Than install it and than restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to References->Add Reference->Framework and select System.ComponentModel.Composition

Answer (score 0):

You can also install the [System.ComponentModel Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Composition/):

Project > Manage Nuget packages >
Browse System.ComponentModel and install.